# I tried to open new window on button click in Electron.js but Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I have tried multiple solutions to open a new window when the button is clicked in electron.js first I got an error on `require` was undefined, `nodeIntegration: true` helped me to solve it but now the `remote` and `require` is causing an issue. what is the best method to open a new window in the latest version on electron

**index.js**

```
const button = document.getElementById("notifyBtn");
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  createBrowserWindow();
});

function createBrowserWindow() {
  const remote = require("electron").remote;
  const BrowserWindow = remote.BrowserWindow;
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 200,
    width: 300,
  });

  win.loadFile("add.html");
}
```

**main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = require("electron");
const { shell } = require("electron/common");
const path = require("path");
//creating window
function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
      devTools: true,
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
    },
  });
  // loading index file to the window
  win.loadFile("src/index.html");
  win.webContents.openDevTools();
  // setting top menu bar
  const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
      label: "Menu",
      submenu: [{ label: "option 1" }],
      submenu: [{ label: "option 1" }],
      submenu: [
        { label: "option 1" },
        { label: "option 2" },
        {
          label: "Link",
          click() {
            shell.openExternal("https://www.google.com");
          },
        },
        { type: "separator" },
        {
          label: "Exit",
          click() {
            app.quit();
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    { label: "Info" },
  ]);

  Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
}

//start a window
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();
});

// to Quit when window is closed
app.on("window-all-closed", function () {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") app.quit();
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="price-contaier">
        <div class="subtext">Current BTC USD</div>
        <h1 id="price">loading...</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="goal-container">
        <p>
          <img src="" alt="" />
          <div id="targetPrice">Choose a Traget Price</div>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="right-container">
        <button id="notifyBtn">Notify me when...</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "crypto-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^15.3.0"
  }
}
```

**Error**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The remote module was [removed in Electron 14](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/main/docs/breaking-changes.md#removed-remote-module).

You can open windows from the renderer process with the `window.open` API:

```
window.open('https://github.com', '_blank', 'width=200,height=200')
```

See: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/window-open#windowopenurl-framename-features